# How can I return user- specific information from MS Graph API?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get a list of planner plans associated with a user. I can do this in Graph Explorer (logged in with my work Microsoft account) using the following API call:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<my-email>/planner/plans
```

However, I need to use a token from my console app, as I need to run it as a scheduled task with no user intervention. From my app I get an access denied error:

> **401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.** You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the
>   credentials that you supplied.

I can successfully call "generic" methods (such as `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups` ) but not something specific to a user.

I am getting my token using:

```
context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<my_tenant");
context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com", new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey));
```

How can I give this token the necessary permissions to read stuff like planner? I've tried in the **Azure Portal** under the **Azure AD** blade:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, I assume you want to list the plans of a user.

Based on my test, we can use the follow simple code:

```
public PlanClientService()
    {
        _serviceClient = GraphSdkHelper.GetGraphServiceClient();
    }
    public async Task<IList<PlannerPlan>> PlannerPlansAsync()
    {
        var plans = await _serviceClient.Me.Planner.Plans.Request().GetAsync();
        return plans;
    }
```

We can refer to [the simple code](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-connect-sample) for more detail.

And according to the error description, you should add the `Group.Read.All, Group.ReadWrite.All` permission when you get the accesstoken.